# How to create a matrix of objects of a custom Class in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, matrix

I am working on an epidemic simulator. However, I have run into a problem: I need to create a matrix of my custom class `Location()` which has a **init**() method of `__init(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name)__`. All of these parameters are supposed to be random (excluding the name).

The only problem I encounter is when trying to create a matrix / map of these custom locations which I would use in my simulation.
I have tried:

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 5

row = [Location() for i in range(num_rows)]
mat = [list(row) for i in range(num_cols)]

mat[0][0] = Location(...)
```

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 5

row = [Location() for i in range(num_rows)]
mat = [list(row) for i in range(num_cols)]

mat.append(Location(...))
```

```
w, h = 5, 5
Matrix = [[Location() for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

Matrix.append(Location(...))
```

```
w, h = 5, 5
Matrix = [[Location() for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]

Matrix[0][0] = Location(...)
```

All of these encounter the same type error: "Expected type 'List[Location]' (matched generic type '_T'), got 'Location' instead."

I have not been working with Python for very long so I do not know of any workarounds to this and I have found nothing online to help with this.

My full code currently looks like this:

```
import random


# Location class
class Location:

    def __init__(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name):
        self._x_coords = x_coords
        self._y_coords = y_coords
        self._population = population
        self._name = name

    # GETTERS VVVV
    def get_x_coords(self):
        return self._x_coords

    def get_y_coords(self):
        return self._y_coords

    def get_population(self):
        return self._population

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name


# Need to initialize a matrix of Location() here
```

Comment: I know you're not asking for a code review, but getters are not very Pythonic, consider using the @property decorator. To answer your question remove list from around row which is giving you a list of list(list(location)) as the error states you want a list of list(location).

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: I tried a few of your examples and None of them produced an error.

Comment: `def __index__(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name):` - is that a typo? Should it be `def __init__(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name):`?

Comment: Oh, just added that as an answer (__ index __ vs __ init __ ) :) Oh, well. Good that you found it. Good luck with the simulation. Any plans to publish the results somewhere?

Comment: @wwii was definitely a typo. I fixed it in my code. Also, my IDE (Pycharm) just gave it a warning and said that there *would* be an error. I never ran it because the IDE wouldn't let me use the error-producing list anywhere else.

Comment: @OpalApps I planned on maybe running it a bunch of times and publishing my results on YouTube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like this

```py
num_col = 5
num_row = 5
mat = [[] for i in range(num_row)] # create a list of empty lists

for row in range(num_row):
    for col in range(num_col):
        mat[row].append(Location(...)) # populate each list with Locations
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `__init__(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name)` in your `Location` class instead of `__index__(self, x_coords, y_coords, population, name)`.

Here is the code (Location constructor parameters simplified):

```
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 5

class Location:
    def __index__(self, locationIndex=0):
        print( "Location::__index__(" + str( locationIndex) + ")")

    def __init__(self, locationIndex=0):
        print( "Location::__init__(" + str( locationIndex) + ")")

    row = [ Location(i) for i in range( 0, num_rows) ]
    mat = [ list(row) for i in range( 0, num_cols)]

    mat[0][0] = Location(...)
    print( mat)
```

and the output is:

```
Location::__init__(0)
Location::__init__(1)
Location::__init__(2)
Location::__init__(3)
Location::__init__(4)
Location::__init__(Ellipsis)
```

Note, not `Location::__index__()` but `Location::__init__()` will be called up on the list comprehension.

The last call `Location::__init__(Ellipsis)` comes from `print( mat)`.